# Find a variable in array from a GET variable and remove string from the array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I need to get the array index number by looking for text in the array but then I need to delete that array index and pass whats left to a txt file?

Each array index is an explode of a multi line txt file, which also contains other text (including HTML) in the lines, but does not contain any repeats in other lines of the text I'm looking for.

So far I have this being able to delete the first array index removing that line in the txt file but I need to find what array index the $something variable is in and delete that line...

```
if($_GET['delete'] == $something){
    $create = fopen("info.txt", "r+t");
    $oldstuff = fread($create, 1024);
    $array = explode("\n", file_get_contents("info.txt"));
    unset($array[$something]);
    $string = implode("\n",$array);
    $newstuff = fopen("info.txt", "w+");
    fwrite($newstuff, $string);
    fclose($newstuff);
    fclose($create);
```

Comment: Ohh, Errr, Whattttt?

Comment: it would really help if you'd show us the contents of the array, the text you're searching for (wherever that comes from??) and what you then expect the text file to look like after your code has run. Your description is rather vague and confusing, unfortunately.

Comment: When you write a question, read it back to yourself. Pretend it was not you that wrote it! Then ask yourself, could I understand and then try and provide an answer to the question. _If not, rewrite it until the answer is YES_

Comment: Edited to hopefully make more sense?

Comment: You've removed the line _"Each array index contains more in the string than just the bit of text I am looking for"_. Is that not true anymore? If it is, than it's a pretty important part and should be left in since `array_search()` will only give you exact matches and not partial matches. Also, you should still show us some example contents.

Comment: Yes I have realised the mistake and added it back in...

Comment: I presume I need to use the in_array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `info.txt` contains multiple lines of text, and each line being exploded into an array. you can use php function **[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)** to find the line which contains the given string. so you can code it something like this:

```
if($_GET['delete'] == $something) {
    $create     = fopen("info.txt", "r+t");
    $oldstuff   = fread($create, 1024);
    $array      = explode("\n", file_get_contents("info.txt"));

    $find   = 'test'; // string you want to find
    $key    = array_search ($find , $array); // returns the index key if found or false if not found 
    if ($key) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }

    $string = implode("\n", $array);
    $newstuff = fopen("info.txt", "w+");
    fwrite($newstuff, $string);
    fclose($newstuff);
    fclose($create);
}
```

Comment: This is almost what I need however this seems to remove the first line of the text regardless of what the find string is?? It seems to be setting $key to [0] whatever happens?

Comment: 80% of that code is redundant. Please revise the code.

Comment: And it is also wrong. Have you tested the code before posting?

Comment: Yes. The code works fine and does what I need it to do except the array index it removes is always the first line of the txt file

Comment: What's up with the `$create` and `$oldstuff`-variables? They are defined but never used. Also, if you use `file()` instead of `file_get_contents()`, you will already get the contents as an array with each row as an item so you wouldn't need `explode()`. You could also remove the `fopen()` when you want to store the new data. Just use `file_put_contents()` instead.

Comment: `if ($key)` should also be `if ($key !== false)` since `array_search()` returns false if the string wasn't found but can return 0 (which is faley) if it was found in the first array item. However, before the OP rewrote the question, it said _""Each array index contains more in the string than just the bit of text I am looking for""_. If that's the case, then `array_search()` is the wrong tool.

Comment: This is true ... there is other text in the lines and therefore the reason array_search isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to achieve it...

```
if($_GET['delete']){
$name = "<li class='drinks'><span class='names'>".htmlspecialchars($_GET["delete"])."</span>";
$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents("info.txt"));
$key = array_search($user , $array);
if($key !== false) {
  unset($array[$key]);
};
$string = implode("\n", $array);
file_put_contents("info.txt", $string);
```

Thanks for the help. Realised that the other content was always the same on each line of the txt file so I could include that in the array_search :)